# Perl DBD::CSV - SQL Syntax - "AND" clause is not working properly

Tags: perl, dbi

I am running Perl 5.10 on Ubuntu 10.04 and using perl DBI module.
I am trying to use the "AND" condition in "WHERE" clause in SQL Query under Perl DBI. I am using the DBD::CSV driver.

Please consoider below test.csv:

```
OS,RELEASE,VERSION
Ubuntu,Warty,4
Ubuntu,Hoary,5
Ubuntu,Breezy,5
Fedora,Yarrow,1
Fedora,Tettnang,2
Fedora,Stentz,4
```

Here I want to retrieve the VERSION for Fedora Stentz.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use DBI;

my $table = "test.csv";

my $dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:") or die "Cannot connect to the CSV file: $DBI::errstr()";
$dbh->{RaiseError} = 1;
$dbh->{TraceLevel} = 0;

my $query = "select VERSION from $table where OS='Fedora' and RELEASE='Yarrow'";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare ($query);
$sth->execute ();
$sth->dump_results();
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Here is hte output;

```
0 rows
```

If I use Placeholders in my query instead of the actual values as below:

```
my $query = "select VERSION from $table where OS=? and RELEASE=?";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare ($query);
$sth->execute ('Fedora', 'Yarrow');
$sth->dump_results();
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

then the output is an error as below:

```
DBD::CSV::st execute failed: You passed 2 parameters where 0 required [for Statement "select VERSION from test.csv where OS=? and RELEASE=?"] at count.pl line 14.
DBD::CSV::st execute failed: You passed 2 parameters where 0 required [for Statement "select VERSION from test.csv where OS=? and RELEASE=?"] at count.pl line 14.
```

But if i use only one condition in hte WEHRE clause as below, then the script gives me the right output:

```
my $query = "select VERSION from $table where OS=?";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare ($query);
$sth->execute ('Fedora');
$sth->dump_results();
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

And hte output is:

```
'1'
'2'
'4'
3 rows
```

so, the bottom line and my issue is, when I write the "and" condition in "where" clause, it is not working. I doubt that there is something wrong with my query syntax but not able to figure that out yet. Any pointers or suggestion would be of great help.

Also, I have an ongoing thread on perlmonks for the same issue: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=990214

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your snippets work fine for me. Make sure your modules are up to date. From [Devel::VersionDump](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aVersionDump) (called on exit):

```
Perl version: v5.16.0 on linux (/home/eric/usr/perlbrew/perls/5.16.0t/bin/perl)
AutoLoader                      -     5.72
Carp                            -     1.26
Clone                           -     0.31
Config                          -  Unknown
Cwd                             -  3.39_02
DBD::CSV                        -     0.36
DBD::File                       -     0.40
DBI                             -    1.620
DBI::DBD::SqlEngine             -     0.03
DBI::SQL::Nano                  - 1.014600
Data::Dumper                    - 2.135_06
Devel::VersionDump              -     0.02
DynaLoader                      -     1.14
Errno                           -     1.15
Exporter                        -     5.66
Exporter::Heavy                 -     5.66
Fcntl                           -     1.11
File::Basename                  -     2.84
File::Spec                      -  3.39_02
File::Spec::Unix                -  3.39_02
IO                              -  1.25_06
IO::File                        -     1.16
IO::Handle                      -     1.33
IO::Seekable                    -      1.1
List::Util                      -     1.23
Params::Util                    -     1.07
SQL::Dialects::AnyData          -     1.33
SQL::Dialects::Role             -     1.33
SQL::Eval                       -     1.33
SQL::Parser                     -     1.33
SQL::Statement                  -     1.33
SQL::Statement::Function        -     1.33
SQL::Statement::Functions       -     1.33
SQL::Statement::Operation       -     1.33
SQL::Statement::Placeholder     -     1.33
SQL::Statement::RAM             -     1.33
SQL::Statement::Term            -     1.33
SQL::Statement::TermFactory     -     1.33
SQL::Statement::Util            -     1.33
Scalar::Util                    -     1.23
SelectSaver                     -     1.02
Symbol                          -     1.07
Text::CSV_XS                    -     0.91
Tie::Hash                       -     1.04
XSLoader                        -     0.16
base                            -     2.18
bytes                           -     1.04
constant                        -     1.23
overload                        -     1.18
overloading                     -     0.02
sort                            -     2.01
strict                          -     1.07
unicore::Heavy.pl               -  Unknown
unicore::lib::Perl::Word.pl     -  Unknown
unicore::lib::Perl::_PerlIDS.pl -  Unknown
utf8                            -     1.09
utf8_heavy.pl                   -  Unknown
vars                            -     1.02
warnings                        -     1.13
warnings::register              -     1.02
```

Comment: That was so quick and easy. I wasted the whole day working on it and it turned out to be screwed modules. per you suggestion, When I ran VersoinDump, the two Modules "SQL::Statement" and "SQL::Parser" said "unknown" and all others showed a version number. So I reinstalled "SQL::Statement" and ran VersionDump and it showed up with the version number. Later my script ran fine as well. Thank you very much ikegami for your time and help. I would have never thought in my wildest dream that this is a corrupt module issue. THANK YOU !!!